# Check if entity is empty in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying find out if my $appointment entity is empty or not in CakePHP, but this does not work:

```
$appointment = $this->Appointments->get($id);

if($appointment->isEmpty()) {
    throw new NotFoundException("invalid appointment");
}
```

**Error:**

> Error: Call to undefined method
>   App\Model\Entity\Appointment::isEmpty()

What is the correct way of doing this? The [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#checking-if-a-query-or-resultset-is-empty) say it works for `Query` or `ResultSet`, but I need it for the mentioned code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the exceptions manually. Follow this approach:

```
/* Mention this on top of your page */
use Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;

public function test()
{
    try {
        $appointment = $this->Appointments->get($id);
    } catch (RecordNotFoundException $e) {
        $appointment = [];
    } 
    if (!$appointment) {
        $this->Flash->error(__("Invalid appointment"));
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to [Get a Single Entity by Primary Key](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key). If that's the case, you shouldn't have to verify that it's found and throw your own exception if it isn't. From what I saw in the docs, the framework will automatically do that for you.

> If the get operation does not find any results a Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException will be raised. You can either catch this exception yourself, or allow CakePHP to convert it into a 404 error.

Comment: Or just use find() instead, never try to catch that error if you can prevent this by design.